# Opening up an local network with DHCP whith own IP-segment

Tags: ip, dhcp, access-point, wlan

I initially thought, that this is a very basic task, but somehow I faced some Issues.

I have an TP-Link Access Point that is connected with a static IP in an existing network at adress 192.168.225.185. (Mask: 255.255.255.0, GW: 192.168.225.1).

I now want the AP to open up an own network, that **does not extend the existing network (192.168.225.x) over the air, but creates an own network, that is separated with an own IP-range. (e.g. 192.168.0.x).**

At the TP-Link GUI, I cannot set an own network range. It is just possible to Apply DHCP within the 225.x-Network. If I want to change, it says, that the DHCP-Range has to be within the APs network.

So: How would I create an own, local WLAN with a personally set adress range.

My AP is: TP-LINK TL-WA901ND.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you need separate network - you need a router, but WA901ND is an access point. Access points are only bridging Ethernet and Wi-fi. There is no way WLAN and LAN ports of access point have addresses in different networks.